# Конфликт в коде с $

Tags: bash, echo, awk

Код внизу копирует названия файлов `.xml` в текстовый файл.

```
for a in $(cd any/directory; ls *xml)
do 
   echo "awk 'NR>1 {print $0}' < ../$a > tmp_file" >> data.txt
done
```

Но при попытке вставить данную строчку в текстовый файл `awk 'NR>1 {print $0}'` возникают проблемы из за `$0`. В итоге из за этого на выходе получается:

```
awk 'NR>1 {print bash}' < ../любой_файл.xml > tmp_file
```

Как можно решить данную проблему?

Comment: Представляю, что будет, когда вы почувствуете радость от *python* (shell -- довольно сложный язык программирования, учитывая ваш предыдущий вопрос, вы как мне кажется выбрали не самый лёгкий путь решения).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

«экранируйте» символ `$`, добавив перед ним «обратный слэш» `\`:

```
\$
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!